# how to separate a 10-digit phone number into two parts

Tags: sed, ksh

For example, I get a phone number like `9191234567`, how could I separate it into two parts, with the first part containing the three leading digits `919` and the other part containing the rest seven digits `1234567`? After that, I want to store these two parts into two different variables in `ksh`.

I don't know if this could be done with `sed`?

Comment: Separate them into two parts and then do what with them? Write them to stdout with a space in between?

Comment: Substring from 0-2 and then another substring from 3-9?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: After separating, I want to store the two parts into two different script variables, could this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this :

```
echo "9191234567" | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{7\}\)$/\1 \2/'
```

To store each part in a separate variable, you could do this :

```
phone="9191234567"
part1=$(echo $phone | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]\{7\}$/\1/')
part2=$(echo $phone | sed 's/^[0-9]\{3\}\([0-9]\{7\}\)$/\1/')
```

Or even more concise :

```
read part1 part2 <<< $(echo "9191234567" | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{7\}\)$/\1 \2/')
```

Comment: Thanks. Could I store these `\1` and `\2` into two script variables?

Comment: Nice trick, Eric! But it looks the operator `<<<` is not supported in either `ksh` or `ksh93`.

Comment: Ouch... ok. I use dash, so I didn't know that. I assumed it was supported. Well I guess you'll have to use the 2nd solution. :)

Comment: Yup, the 2nd solution works well enough. Regrettably, bash is not always available in AIX machines, :(

Comment: @QiangXu It seems the 3rd solution does work fine in ksh. I just tested it. :)

Comment: @QiangXu, If your version of ksh does not have here-strings, it might have process substitutions: `read part1 part2 < <(echo "9191234567" | sed 's/^.../& /')`

Answer (score 5):

`cut` should work

```
echo '9191234567' | cut --characters 1-3,4- --output-delimiter ' '
919 1234567
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 9191234567 | sed 's/^\([1-9]\{3\}\)\([1-9]*\)/\1\-\2/'
```

Will print `919-1234567`

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash`

```
$ phone=9191234567
$ regex="^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{7})$"
$ [[ $phone =~ $regex ]] && part1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" && part2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
$ echo $part1
919
$ echo $part2
1234567
```

Comment: Nice one! :) Didn't know this variable.

Comment: @EricCitaire Thanks Eric, actually this answer shouldn't be posted since it's not available on OP's shell. I just posted it as reference for others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure ksh, take number, print as two separate strings, separated by white space.

```
function split_at_third {
    typeset number=$1 a b
    b=${number#???} && a=${number%$b}
    print $a $b
}
```